# Rings with no zero divisors and an additional Hypothesis are commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So, inspired by the question [Finite integral domains are commutative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080388/finite-integral-domains-are-commutative), i was wondering if the next generalization is also true:

- Let $A$ be an integral domain (using the terminology of the linked question), such that every element $a \in A$ generates a finite subring. Then, is $A$ commutative? (WLOG, we can suppose that these subrigs are proper, because otherwise the answer is clear)

Now, here is what i tried (with little to no success):

1. Strengthening the hypothesis by requiring that every proper subring of $A$ is finite, by following the answer to the linked question, $a,b \in A$ commute if the subring generated by these two elements is proper. Not an answer, but at least something.
2. If we also ask that $A$ has a unit element $1$, then the subring $\widetilde{u}$ generated by $u \in A-\left \{ 0_A \right \}$ is finite and integral, so by https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Ring_with_No_Proper_Zero_Divisors_is_Field (this link was also mentioned in the question linked above) it is a field, so $u$ is invertible in $\widetilde{u}$, and so it is invertible in $A$. Then, $A$ would be a division ring. Still, not what i am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ring generated by $a\ne0 \in A$ is finite then $a^k=a^{k+d}$ for some $k,d\ge 1$. Therefore since $a(a^{k-1}-a^{k-1+d})=0$,..., so $a=a^{d+1}$. Then for every $b\ne0 \in A$, $ab-a^{d+1}b=0$, hence $a^db=b$. Similarly, $ba^d=b$. So $a^d$ is the identity element 1. Thus for every $a\ne0\in A$ there exists $d=d(a)$ such that $a^d=1$. Thus $A$ is a periodic division ring. So $A$ is a field, hence commutative.

Answer (score 0):

To state it in terms of the solution you linked to:

It's quite clear that a "domain" in which every element generates a finite subring is a division ring, because each such finite subring is a field and even share the same identity (by the linked solution.) Obviously then all nonzero elements are invertible.

So the trick is to prove commutativity.  At the moment I can think of no better way than the one JCAA alludes to, which is appealing to [Jacobson's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32032/on-a-theorem-of-jacobson) that periodic rings are commutative. (This ring is periodic since, by finiteness and cancellation, $a^{i_a}=a$ for some integer $i_a > 1$ depending on $a$.)

Maybe something more elementary can be worked out by assuming $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ or $ab-ba$ is nonzero and then looking at the field generated by them...